# Configuring Incremental Refresh in Power BI :: We cannot apply operator < to types Date and Text

Tags: powerbi, azure-blob-storage, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm pulling data from several CSV from a Storage Account and the refresh takes 1h.

I would like to speed up things so I followed [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kui_1G6kQIQ) about how to setup an incremental refresh.

I setup the two parameters as explained at [4:24](https://youtu.be/Kui_1G6kQIQ?t=264) .

Then at [4:49](https://youtu.be/Kui_1G6kQIQ?t=289) he asks to right click on the step and see if the View Native Query is available. In my case it's grayed out:

[image]

Then at [5:10](https://youtu.be/Kui_1G6kQIQ?t=310) he says that if the step is grayed out you should put the step a bit earlier. But as soon as I do that things breaks:

[image]

If I move it very earlier it says:

```
Expression.Error: The field 'date' of the record wasn't found.
Details:
    Content=[Binary]
    Name=Invoices MACC 2020-2023/2022/2022-1.csv
    Extension=.csv
    Date accessed=
    Date modified=6/12/2023 14:18:01
    Date created=
    Attributes=
        Content Type=application/vnd.ms-excel
        Kind=Excel File
        Size=311677697
    Folder Path=https://mycontainer.blob.core.windows.net/cost-management-export
    Transform File=[Table]
```

If I move it just before the previous one:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator < to types Date and Text.
Details:
    Operator=<
    Left=1/1/2020
    Right=1/2/2022
```

Wait, what?

> We cannot apply operator < to types Date and Text.

Isn't that exactly what you are supposed to do!

Then I click Close & Apply and my dashboards are broken, just blank:

[image]

Comment: Unless you use the RangeStart/RangeEnd parameters to skip whole files, Incremental Refresh may not help much.  If Power Query has to read the whole file and then filter, that might take just as much time.  But converting RangeStart/RangeEnd to other data types is covered here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-configure#convert-datetime-to-integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is: [Azure Blob Storage is not supported by Query Folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding#sources-that-support-folding) .

One guy proposed [a solution](https://pbi-guy.com/2022/07/14/how-to-use-incremental-refresh-on-any-data-source/) but that is only for the datamart.